# Getting an error when trying to webscrape a username with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

```
C:\Users\Coach\Desktop\a\getuser.js:24
    const txt = await el2.getProperty('textContent');
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProperty')
    at scrapeProduct (C:\Users\Coach\Desktop\a\getuser.js:24:27)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

C:\Users\Coach\Desktop\a>PAUSE
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Error code(above)
This is my code I want to run (below)

```
console.clear();

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

console.log(`
_______  _______  _______  ___            _______  __   __  _______ 
|       ||       ||   _   ||   |          |       ||  |_|  ||       |
|       ||   _   ||  |_|  ||   |          |    ___||       ||    ___|
|       ||  | |  ||       ||   |          |   |___ |       ||   |___ 
|      _||  |_|  ||       ||   |___  ___  |    ___| |     | |    ___|
|     |_ |       ||   _   ||       ||   | |   |___ |   _   ||   |___ 
|_______||_______||__| |__||_______||___| |_______||__| |__||_______|
                                     
`);


async function scrapeProduct(url) {
   
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const [el2] = await page.$x('//*[@id="collapse-1-2"]/div/ul/li[1]/text()');
    const txt = await el2.getProperty('textContent');
    const rawTxt = await txt.jsonValue();


    console.log({rawTxt})

}

scrapeProduct('https://plancke.io/hypixel/player/stats/coalwork#BedWars');
```

I want to return the number of coins this player has but it gives me this error. I tested the code with a different scrapeProduct and page.$x on amazon and it worked, but now trying to do it on any other website gives me the error above.

I eventually want to make it so you input the username you want and it will return the coins of the player and also be able to be able to continuously look up players instead of stopping after one.

Comment: Your code works for me. The data is there in the static HTML so you might not even need Puppeteer for this, just a plain HTTP request and Cheerio or another lightweight HTML parser.

Comment: I'm not using cheerio. Im using puppeteer because I've never touched this before and it was the easiest to understand.

Comment: I realize you're not using Cheerio, I'm just making a suggestion as an aside which would speed up the code quite a bit--Puppeteer is probably overkill here. If you do stick with Pupp, at least use `{waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"}` to speed up your `goto`. The main point of my comment is to let you know that I can't reproduce your error, so you'll need to provide more context as to how you're triggering that error. Does it sometimes work and sometimes fail? Maybe you're being rate limited after repeated requests?

Comment: Figured it out! thanks for your help. I also added in looking up certain players. I just need to know how to repeat the code after you look someone up

Comment: Figured what out? There shouldn't have been any problem with the code. If there was, what did you fix? To repeat the code, add a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You added extra text() in selector.
Using this change code

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function scrapeProduct(url) {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const [el2] = await page.$x('//*[@id="collapse-1-2"]/div/ul/li[1]');
    const txt = await el2.getProperty('textContent');
    const rawTxt = await txt.jsonValue();

    console.log({rawTxt});
    await browser.close();
}

scrapeProduct('https://plancke.io/hypixel/player/stats/coalwork#BedWars');
```

Result

```
$ node coin.js
{ rawTxt: 'Coins: 1,154,408' }
```